# Numpy where is only returning Boolean value

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have below doubt.
I am comparing values of 2 columns using numpy `where` method.

```py
Np.where(df.col1 == df col2, df.col1, False)
```

This is returning only `True` or `False` instead of returning value of `col1` when both `col1` and `col2` values are equal.

Comment: Please edit the question with some more info including what the df looks like

Comment: have you look at pandas [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) method ?

Comment: Examine `df.col1 == df col2`  by itself.  `where` action depends on its inputs.

Comment: @hpauji.... i had examined the values for both columns and both values matches. If match, then it should print value of either of the column, but it is printing 0 or True for me. I don't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.where(condition, x, y)
```

returns elements chosen from x or y depending on **condition**.
When the **condition** return True, np.where choices in x otherwise it choices in y.
The problem is where you have put False.
For more explanation, visits  [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: I don't think this answer their question. They want `df.col1` if both are equal, otherwise `False`, so their params are in the right place.

Comment: @tdy, without knowledge of `df` we really can't "answer" the question. But what is the question?  Is it "what is wrong" or "how do I do x?

Comment: @tdy...yes that is correct understanding.